# How to reload the data in UITableView in iPhone in the same view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview, reloaddata

I am developing an iPhone application, in a view, I have placed `UITextView` and `UITableView` in the same `ViewController`. What i need to do is, after entering the data in the textview, the user will click on a button placed below. After clicking on the button, the data entered in the textview should be loaded in the tableview. But it is not working so.

Here, what i have done is, I have written the below code inside the button action,

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Any suggestions much appreciated

Comment: Add some more code will you ? it'll help to decipher ur problem...

Comment: are you updating your array with the text from uitextview ?? give more code..

Comment: Actually, I am fetching the values from the URL and displaying it in the UITableView, once the user enters the data in textview, the same data i will send by the URL and then the reloaded data should display in table

Comment: @jireh how much is your requirement for this question itself ?? Please stick to one issue.....

Comment: @Gill only this was my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are updating the `NSMutableArray` with the new value, that you are using to fill data in your `UITableView`.

On the click of the button,

```
[arrValues addObject:txtBox.text];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Yes, i am adding the array with the value i am entering. Because, after entering data and button click, I just navigate to previous view and then to same view displays the added data in the UITableView but it is not loaded in the same view itself.

Comment: Check properly which table exactly you are reloading after entering new value, present view's table or previous view's table?

Comment: Then make sure you are returning correct number of rows in numberOfRowsInSection. You shud put ur code. Then it can be easy finding your problem.

Comment: In ViewDidLoad, I am fetching the data from the URL and adding the contents return from the url in the array (NSMutable). And, I have written [array count] in the numberOfRowsInSection, and it is working fine. On the button click (function), I am just passing the entered value in the textview to the URL (php) and it is also working fine and data is also added to the same url. But, the value doesn't display in the tableview in the same instance. But it displays correctly when i go to the previous view and get into the same view again, the value is fetched from the url and it displays correctly

Comment: And i have added, [self.tableView reloadData], in the ViewDidLoad, ViewwillAppear and also inside the button action. help me.

Answer (score 1):

This method handle your rowCount of `TableView`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrayData count];
}
```

And this method will make your cell and showing cell data.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So you will have to add `textField.text` in that `array` which you're using for `numberOfRowsInSection:` and  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
-(void)buttonClick:(id)sender
 {
     [arrayData addObject:textField.text];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
 }
```

And make sure `textField.text` should not be empty other wise data will not be visible.
After calling `[self.tableView reloadData]` method all `tableView` delegates method will be call again and `arrayData` will increase the `numberOfRows` for your `tableView`.

**EDIT:**
As you're saying in comment that you're navigating the view so each time your `viewDidLoad:` will be call and your array will have the same object which your initialize in `viewDidLoad:` if you want that your `array` remain same `objects` then dont initialize it static, use `plist` or `Database` and save your `array` data in `Database` in `viewDidDisappear:` method and refresh your `array` in `viewWillAppear:` method before adding your `tableView`.